# Only show databases to user in which he has db_owner rights

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an SQL Server with several users and databases. The permissions are imho simple:

- **user1** is db_owner of **user1_db1**
- **user2** is db_owner of **user2_db1**
- **user3** is db_owner of **user3_db1**
- **user3** is db_owner of **user3_db2**

If a user logs in to the server with Management Studio, he sees **all** databases. He has no rights on it (obviously OK). But he sees them. Which is not optimal.

How can I setup the SQL Server, that when a user logs in, he only gets the databases in which he is db_owner?

Answer (score 1):

See [Hide SQL database from Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio?s=65650a81-d3d4-4267-b1f9-558375b73d7d) on stackoverflow (why it's there is beyond me but the taxonomy here is bizzare to say the least)

Comment: That doesn't work. If I revoke the VIEW ANY DATABASE rights from role "public", it hides all databases from all users. I think that is because all users are in the "public" server role.

Comment: yes users can only see databases they are the owner of.  I tried the instructions in this answer ande they seemed to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio/1430615#1430615

Answer (score 0):

You can Deny access to see them for your instance via Server Properties/ Permissions/ and set deny for login for View Any Database right.

Hope this helps :)